# Wrong results on queries with join for some MariaDB versions

Tags: join, mariadb

I found that on some versions of MariaDB server some simple queries return wrong results for certain data.

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab_parent` (
  `id` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `tab_child` (
  `id` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` bigint(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `tab_parent` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And a view which counts how many children has a parent:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `tab_parent_view` AS 
  SELECT `tab_parent`.*, 
  COUNT(`tab_child`.`id`) AS `child_count` 
  FROM (`tab_parent` LEFT JOIN `tab_child` ON(`tab_child`.`parent_id` = `tab_parent`.`id`))
GROUP BY `tab_parent`.`id`;
```

With a sample data like here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0a89cb2a4bec635766313c3c59cd923c the 2 queries do not return the same number of records for versions 10.2.27 and 10.4.8 of MariaDB. But the results are correct for versions 10.1.43, 10.3.15, 10.3.16 and 10.4.12.

```
SELECT * FROM tab_parent_view WHERE f_date>='2020-02-07' AND f_date<'2020-02-08';
SELECT * FROM tab_parent      WHERE f_date>='2020-02-07' AND f_date<'2020-02-08';
```

For the view only 2 records are returned, but for the table all the 4 existing ones:

[image: Query results]

Is this a known bug in MariaDB? I would like to know what causes this and on which versions is it fixed. For MySQL I did not found this problem.

Comment: This looks like fiddle or used MariaDB version bug. All another versions of MySQL/MariaDB gives correct result.

Comment: @Akina it's not a fiddle bug. I have MariaDB 10.4.8 installed on my machine and it happens the same.

Comment: Try to change applied DBMS on your fiddle. 10.3 and 10.4 gives correct result whereas 10.2 fails.

Comment: I know that. I just want to find out which versions are affected. I have many clients with different versions, and I would like to know which ones must be updated.

Comment: I think that create a small test script and check all versions available for checking for you will be more fast then search for affected versions list (which may be uncomplete)...

Comment: if you recreate view using SQL standard - GROUP BY `tab_parent`.`id`, `tab_parent`.`f_date`, `tab_parent`.`f_value` it will work properly

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ...` shouldn't even run.

Comment: Write a bug report with jira.mariadb.org.  It looks like a new bug with VIEWs introduced between 10.2.15 and 10.2.30; also 10.3.11 and 10.3.21; don't know about 10.4.  The bug does not occur in any of several versions of MySQL and Percona, so I believe it is MariaDB-only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a bug. You use GROUP BY and at that moment server leaves only one random value for f_date in each row. After that you apply your filter for results returned by the query inside the view.
According to MariaDB documentation:

> You can use any of the grouping functions in your select expression.
>   Their values will be calculated based on all the rows that have been
>   grouped together for each result row. If you select a non-grouped
>   column or a value computed from a non-grouped column, it is undefined
>   which row the returned value is taken from. This is not permitted if
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL_MODE is used.
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by/

There is no guarantee that value for non-grouped column will be returned from the same group of rows.
I would recommend you to enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL_MODE and add all non-grouped columns to GROUP BY part or apply grouping functions for them (for example, you could use MAX(f_date)).

Comment: You have a point, but the id is unique, and each group has one row only.

Comment: @TrueSoft As I wrote there is no guarantee that the value for non-grouped column will be from the same row/group.

Comment: @Nikita - No.  The only_full... does not apply since it is grouping by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  That eliminates any ambiguity or need for `MAX()`.  (It is cryptically alluded to with "a value computed from a non-grouped column".)

Comment: @RickJames "a value computed from a non-grouped column" is just some expression based on this non-grouped column. For example "f_value + 1". And as we can see in above quote "it is undefined which row the returned value is taken from". Why do you think f_value should be returned from the same row if you use group by on primary key?

Comment: @Nikita - I have a table of cities in Canada, PK=`id`.  When I `GROUP BY id` the query is happy; when I `GROUP BY province` it says:  "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'world.canada.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by '.  The query is `SELECT * FROM canada GROUP BY ___ LIMIT 3;  The OP is doing `GROUP BY id`.

Comment: @Nikita - What is the "non-grouped" item in question?

Comment: @RickJames "SELECT * FROM tab_parent GROUP BY id" with enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY returns " SQL Error (1055): 'test.tab_parent.f_date' isn't in GROUP BY"